# Node.js serialport access denied

Tags: node.js, serial-port

I am trying to send a string through serialport in node.js with the following code:

```
function createSerialPort() {
  myPort = new SerialPort('COM3', {
    baudRate: 115200, dataBits: 8, parity: 'none', stopBits: 1, flowControl: 0
  })
  myPort.write("135");
}
```

Everytime I run it it gives me this error:

```
(node:8468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Opening COM3: Access denied
(node:8468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8468) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code
```

I have looked everywhere for a fix to this (I am new to using serialport) and the only solution I have found is to do this:

```
function createSerialPort() {
  myPort = new SerialPort('COM3', {
    baudRate: 115200, dataBits: 8, parity: 'none', stopBits: 1, flowControl: 0
  }, true)
  myPort.write("135");
}
```

That solution then gives me this:

```
(node:18192) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: callback.call is not a function
    at SerialPort._error (C:\examplepath\node_modules\@serialport\stream\lib\index.js:198:14)
    at C:\examplepath\node_modules\@serialport\stream\lib\index.js:242:12
(node:18192) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:18192) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Adding error handler `myPort.on('error', function(err) { console.log('Error: ', err.message); })` should fix it

Comment: Also the third argument to the SerialPort should be function not a Boolean. So this `myPort = new SerialPort('COM3', ..., function(){...});` should also fix the problem.